# Glitch in WordPress single.php Infinite Scroll/Pagination Loop

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I've created a quick pagination on a single.php file in order to use infinite scroll in a loop at the bottom of the page. Here's the code I used to create my 'nextSelector' and 'navSelector' for the infinite scroll:

```
<?php
    $next_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'2';
?>

<ul class="single-pagination">         
     <li><a class="next pagination-item" href="<?php echo $next_url; ?>/">Next</a></li>
</ul><!--single-pagination-->
```

This works fine because it creates the 'next ' page to get the infinite scroll started. My `navSelector` in the infinite scroll is `ul.single-pagination` and my `nextSelector` is `a.next.pagination-item`. This all works fine on most pages but when I visit a page that has a number at the end of the URL, the infinite scroll changes the number instead of changing the appended number on the URL. For example, if I had a URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/this-post-2/
```

It would load the first iteration of the infinite scroll successfully, which would be:

```
http://www.example.com/this-post-2/2/
```

and then on the next iteration would throw a 404 error on this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/this-post-3/2/
```

Though it should be looking for:

```
http://www.example.com/this-post-2/3/
```

Short of breaking apart the JS code for the infinite scroll, is there any way to customize the URL that the infinite scroll look for?

### EDIT

This is related to the RegEx expression in the jquery.infinitescroll.min.js that is altering the URL. Here is the code that I am working on altering. I will post the answer here if no one beats me to it:

```
t = t.match(/^(.*?)\b2\b(.*?$)/).slice(1);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution to this lies in the jquery.infinitescroll.js (or jquery.infinitescroll.min.js file). The RegEx that the author used on this does not take into account these types of URLs.

I created a fork of the code in my GitHub account that can be accessed here:

https://github.com/MillerMedia/infinite-scroll

Basically, a RegEx expression of this:

```
t = t.match(/^(.*?2)\b2\b(.*?$)/).slice(1);
```

Is placed before this one:

```
t = t.match(/^(.*?)\b2\b(.*?$)/).slice(1);
```